# Parsing javascript array with multiple keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, key

Hi I need to parse a JavaScript array that has multiple keys in it. Here is an example of what I need to do. Any help is appreciated.

```
[
    week1{
        Meth:100,
        Marijuana:122,
        pDrugs:12,
    },
    week2{
        Meth:15,
        Marijuana:30,
        pDrugs:22,
    },
]
```

I need this to be broken into separate arrays based on if it is week1 or week2. Thanks again in advance.

The end needs to be like this.

```
week1 = ["Meth:100,Marijuana:122,pDrugs12"] etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON has severe improper formatting.  If it's already an object (which I'm guessing it isn't -- otherwise, you'd be getting unexpected token errors in your browser console), then change the brackets to braces, remove the trailing commas, and add colons after the object items that don't have them (after `week1` and `week2`).

If what you have is a string (obtained from XHR or similar), you'll have to do all the changes mentioned above, as well as enclosing each object item within quotation marks.  It should look like:

```
{
    "week1": {
        "Meth":100,
        "Marijuana":122,
        "pDrugs":12
    },
    "week2": {
        "Meth":15,
        "Marijuana":30,
        "pDrugs":22
    }
}
```

Whatever you're dealing with that's serving such horribly invalid JSON ought to be taken out back and shot.  Be that as it may, this'll require some serious string manipulation.  You're going to have to do some thorough massaging with `String.replace()` and some regular expressions.

After you get the JSON valid, then you can get week1 with JSON.parse and drilling down the resulting object.

```js
function log(what) { document.getElementById('out').value += what + '\n------------------\n'; }

var tree = '[ week1{ Meth:100, Marijuana:122, pDrugs:12, }, week2{ Meth:15, Marijuana:30, pDrugs:22, }, ]';

// string is raw
log(tree);

tree = tree.replace(
  '/\r?\n/g', ''    // remove line breaks to make further regexps easier
).replace(
  '[','{'           // replace [ with {
).replace(
  ']','}'           // replace ] with }
).replace(
  /\w+(?=[\{\:])/g,                      // add quotes to object items
  function($1) { return '"'+$1+'"'; }    // using a lambda function
).replace(
  /"\{/g, '": {'                         // add colon after object items
).replace(
  /,(?=\s*\})/g, ''                      // remove trailing commas
);

// string has been fixed
log(tree);

var obj = JSON.parse(tree);

log('obj.week1 = ' + JSON.stringify(obj.week1));
log('obj.week1.Meth = ' + obj.week1.Meth);
```

```css
#out {
  width: 100%;
  height: 170px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="out"></textarea>
```